# PHP Notice: Uninitialized string offset 0

Tags: php

I'm having an annoying PHP notice error appear since upgrading to PHP 5.4. I can see where its happening but I just don't have the expertise to correct the code and stop the notice.

PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0

Its happening on line 108 of the code which actually refers to this line:
`$contents[$o] = $this->unicode_entity_replace($contents[$o]);`

The function in question is as follows:

```
class unicode_replace_entities {
        public function UTF8entities($content="") {
            $contents = $this->unicode_string_to_array($content);
            $swap = "";
            $iCount = count($contents);
            for ($o=0;$o<$iCount;$o++) {
                $contents[$o] = $this->unicode_entity_replace($contents[$o]);
               $swap .= $contents[$o];
            }
            return mb_convert_encoding($swap,"UTF-8");
        }
```

Any assistance or explanation would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Full code for remainder of the class below (apologies it wasn't included before):

```
            public function unicode_string_to_array( $string ) { //adjwilli
            $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
            $array = "";
            while ($strlen) {
                $array[] = mb_substr( $string, 0, 1, "UTF-8" );
                $string = mb_substr( $string, 1, $strlen, "UTF-8" );
                $strlen = mb_strlen( $string );
            }
            return $array;
        }

        public function unicode_entity_replace($c) { //m. perez
            $h = ord($c{0});   
            if ($h <= 0x7F) {
                return $c;
            } else if ($h < 0xC2) {
                return $c;
            }

            if ($h <= 0xDF) {
                $h = ($h & 0x1F) << 6 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3F);
                $h = "&#" . $h . ";";
                return $h;
            } else if ($h <= 0xEF) {
                $h = ($h & 0x0F) << 12 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3F) << 6 | (ord($c{2}) & 0x3F);
                $h = "&#" . $h . ";";
                return $h;
            } else if ($h <= 0xF4) {
                $h = ($h & 0x0F) << 18 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3F) << 12 | (ord($c{2}) & 0x3F) << 6 | (ord($c{3}) & 0x3F);
                $h = "&#" . $h . ";";
               return $h;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't guess or make us guess, `var_dump($contents, $o)` to see what you're trying to work with here.

Comment: please provide `unicode_string_to_array` code

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments, full code now above.

Answer (score 1):

If you use array syntax on a string such as `$s[1]` it will access the second letter. However, if the string is empty you will get an offset error. You could prevent this using `!empty($s)` or make sure you are really using an array with `is_array()`.

Comment: he does not access $conetnt string as an array in given code

Comment: you don't know about his unicode_string_to_array() function. so you cannot really say. however, I gave a solution for another case too.

Answer (score 0):

How about foreach?

```
class unicode_replace_entities {
        public function UTF8entities($content="") {
            $contents = $this->unicode_string_to_array($content);
            $swap = "";
            $iCount = count($contents);
            foreach ($contents as $k=>$v) {
                $contents[$k] = $this->unicode_entity_replace($v);
               $swap .= $contents[$k];
            }
            return mb_convert_encoding($swap,"UTF-8");
        }
```

Comment: Tried this and now get 'PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this figured out. As pointed out by another helpful soul it was `$array = "";` in unicode_string_to_array function is causing $array to be a string, not an array. It should be initialized using `$array = array();`